# Best way to save a global variable for directives to watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Inside my directive link function I have

```
angular.module('BTWebApplication').directive('singleTrack', ['$timeout', '$rootScope', function ($timeout, $rootScope) {
return {
    scope: {
        top: "&"
    },
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

        $(element).click(function() {
            var a =$(element).offset();
            $rootScope.top = parseInt(a.top);

            $rootScope.gridIndex === $(this).index() ? hidePreview(element) : showPreview(element);

            function showPreview(index) {
                $rootScope.gridIndex = $(element).index();

                console.log('open');
            }
            function hidePreview() {
                 $rootScope.gridIndex = -1;
                 $rootScope.YoutubeID = -1;
            }
        });

    }, 
    controller: function($scope) {

    }
}
```

}]);

This works but I know I shouldn't be using root scope.
What I am trying to accomplish is a variable to save the data so the next time another element is click it will know what the previous value was.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If you could provide more information and code that would help the community much better. Would you be able to provide the full directive code?

Comment: can you show a bit more code that explains why you are using a combination of angular and jquery here?

Comment: `ng-click` would probably simplify scope issues.

Comment: I was told to use click, I was originally using ng-click, should I switch back?

Comment: It's a grid setup, each time the directive is click I need to get the offset top, and I need this to be in each directive scope, so where would I save this information?

Comment: Having a demo or jsfiddle might help give us more information to understand the problem you're facing. As it stands, something doesn't seem right with your directive, but I don't have enough information to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid rootScope since when your application grows in size, it is best not to pollute it, and as well, it gets harder to code and see where the values change etc.

Anyway, initialize the variable outside, meaning like this:

```
$scope.a = 0;

$(element).click(function(){
    $scope.a += 1;
});
```

Now you can use the value inside the directives scope. Note that this only works if the directive is initialized once, because if it gets re-initialized, it will reset the value of a.

However, best would be, if you need persistence, and want to use the value elsewhere in your app, to use a service.